# How to build maven project with ant script?

Tags: java, maven, ant

I have legacy java project which is build on Ant. But a new module project which is build on maven is ongoing project. Problem is I want to build maven project through ant script and create one .ear file which includes legacy and as well as new project dependencies. Or vise-versa I want also find way to run ant script through pom.xml. I tried both ways but couldn't get success.

In my build.xml I put this target. But it won't help

```
<artifact:mvn pom="../../idp/pom.xml" mavenHome="C:\Program Files\Apache\maven">
        <arg value="install"/>
      </artifact:mvn>
```

It shows error in build.xml that 'The prefix "artifact" for element "artifact:mvn" is not bound.'

I also try this:

```
<target name="compile-mvn-init" unless="compile.classpath" xmlns:artifact="urn:maven-artifact-ant">    
            <typedef resource="org/apache/maven/artifact/ant/antlib.xml" uri="urn:maven-artifact-ant"
                classpath="lib/maven-ant-tasks-2.1.3.jar"/> 
            <condition property="maven.repo.local" value="${maven.repo.local}" else="${user.home}/.m2/repository">
                <isset property="maven.repo.local"/>
            </condition>           
            <echo>maven.repo.local=${maven.repo.local}</echo>
            <artifact:localRepository id="local.repository" path="${maven.repo.local}"/> 
            <artifact:pom file="../../idp/pom.xml" id="maven.project"/>
            <artifact:dependencies pathId="compile.classpath" filesetId="compile.fileset" useScope="compile">
                <pom refid="maven.project"/>
                <localRepository refid="local.repository"/>
            </artifact:dependencies>
            <artifact:dependencies pathId="test.classpath" filesetId="test.fileset" useScope="test">
                <pom refid="maven.project"/>
                <localRepository refid="local.repository"/>
            </artifact:dependencies>
            <artifact:dependencies pathId="runtime.classpath" filesetId="runtime.fileset" useScope="runtime">
                <pom refid="maven.project"/>
                <localRepository refid="local.repository"/>
            </artifact:dependencies>
        </target>
```

But it failed says that :

```
compile-mvn-init:
  [typedef] Could not load definitions from resource org/apache/maven/artifact/a
nt/antlib.xml. It could not be found.
     [echo] maven.repo.local=C:\Users\singh.pankaj/.m2/repository
BUILD FAILED
D:\projects\ddev\SL\DEV\RL2016_03\omega\build\build.xml:702: Problem: failed to
create task or type urn:maven-artifact-ant:localRepository
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place
```

.

I edited this part in my build.xml to this actually problem is for path.

```
<target name="compile-server" 
            description="Compiles Application Tier Implementation classes.">

        <javac srcdir="${SOURCE.DIR}" destdir="${BUILD.DIR}" includes="com/emergis/els/server/**/*"
               deprecation="${compile.deprecation}" debug="${compile.debug}" fork="${compile.fork}"
               failonerror="${compile.failonerror}" verbose="${compile.verbose}" classpathref="javac.classpath.id"/>

    </target>

     <target name="compile-mvn-init" unless="compile.classpath" xmlns:artifact="urn:maven-artifact-ant">    
            <typedef resource="org/apache/maven/artifact/ant/antlib.xml" uri="urn:maven-artifact-ant"
                classpath="${basedir}\lib\maven-ant-tasks-2.1.3.jar"/> 
            <condition property="maven.repo.local" value="${maven.repo.local}" else="${user.home}/.m2/repository">
                <isset property="maven.repo.local"/>
            </condition>           
            <echo>maven.repo.local=${maven.repo.local}</echo>
            <artifact:localRepository id="local.repository" path="${maven.repo.local}"/> 
            <artifact:pom file="../../idp/pom.xml" id="maven.project"/>
            <artifact:dependencies pathId="compile.classpath" filesetId="compile.fileset" useScope="compile">
                <pom refid="maven.project"/>
                <localRepository refid="local.repository"/>
            </artifact:dependencies>
            <artifact:dependencies pathId="test.classpath" filesetId="test.fileset" useScope="test">
                <pom refid="maven.project"/>
                <localRepository refid="local.repository"/>
            </artifact:dependencies>
            <artifact:dependencies pathId="runtime.classpath" filesetId="runtime.fileset" useScope="runtime">
                <pom refid="maven.project"/>
                <localRepository refid="local.repository"/>
            </artifact:dependencies>
        </target>
```

Now error was gone but my pom.xml does not execute. It simply says :

```
compile-mvn-init:
     [echo] maven.repo.local=C:\Users\singh.pankaj/.m2/repository
[artifact:dependencies] Downloading: com/oracle/ojdbc14/10.2.0.1.0/ojdbc14-10.2.
0.1.0.pom from repository central at http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
[artifact:dependencies] Unable to locate resource in repository
[artifact:dependencies] [INFO] Unable to find resource 'com.oracle:ojdbc14:pom:1
0.2.0.1.0' in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
[artifact:dependencies] Downloading: com/oracle/weblogi/weblogic/10.3.5/weblogic
-10.3.5.pom from repository central at http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
[artifact:dependencies] Unable to locate resource in repository
[artifact:dependencies] [INFO] Unable to find resource 'com.oracle.weblogi:weblo
gic:pom:10.3.5' in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
[artifact:dependencies] Downloading: com/oracle/weblogi/wlfullclient/10.3.5/wlfu
llclient-10.3.5.pom from repository central at http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
[artifact:dependencies] Unable to locate resource in repository
[artifact:dependencies] [INFO] Unable to find resource 'com.oracle.weblogi:wlful
lclient:pom:10.3.5' in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
```

My target folder in project idp which is based on maven is not updated.

Comment: You can build an Ant project with maven but I don't think you can build a Maven project with Ant. https://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/ But the best way is to migrate legacy to maven.

Comment: Ant has an exec task and that could exec Anything on the command-line. So that would work. Or you could use gradle to run both ant and maven.  http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long research I came out solution. And with the help of I can successfully build my new project along with my legacy project. For this I have change my existing build.xml. I add two more targets "compile-mvn-init" and “compile-idp”.

```
<target name="compile"
            depends="init, with.clover, compile-auth-provider, compile-shared, compile-server, compile-client, compile-mvn-init, compile-idp"
            description="Compiles Java code."/>


<target name="compile-mvn-init" unless="compile.classpath" xmlns:artifact="urn:maven-artifact-ant" >    
            <typedef resource="org/apache/maven/artifact/ant/antlib.xml" uri="urn:maven-artifact-ant"
                classpath="${basedir}\lib\maven-ant-tasks-2.1.3.jar"/> 
            <condition property="maven.repo.local" value="${maven.repo.local}" else="${basedir}/idp_lib">
                <isset property="maven.repo.local"/>
            </condition>  
         <echo>maven.repo.local=${maven.repo.local}</echo>
            <artifact:localRepository id="local.repository" path="${maven.repo.local}"/> 
            <artifact:pom file="../../idp/pom.xml" id="maven.project"/>
            <property name="VERSION" value="${maven.project.version}"/>
            <echo>The version is ${maven.project.version}</echo>
            <property name="ARTIFACT_ID" value="${maven.project.artifactId}"/>
            <echo>The ARTIFACT_ID is ${ARTIFACT_ID}</echo>
            <artifact:dependencies pathId="compile.classpath" filesetId="compile.fileset" useScope="compile">
                <pom refid="maven.project"/>
                <localRepository refid="local.repository"/>
            </artifact:dependencies>
            <artifact:dependencies pathId="test.classpath" filesetId="test.fileset" useScope="test">
                <pom refid="maven.project"/>
                <localRepository refid="local.repository"/>
            </artifact:dependencies>
            <artifact:dependencies pathId="runtime.classpath" filesetId="runtime.fileset" useScope="runtime">
                <pom refid="maven.project"/>
                <localRepository refid="local.repository"/>
            </artifact:dependencies>
        </target> 

<target name="compile-idp" >

        <javac srcdir="../../idp/src" destdir="../../idp/target/idp-0.1/WEB-INF/classes" classpathref="compile.classpath"/>
        <javac srcdir="../../idp/src/main/java" destdir="../../idp/target/classes" classpathref="compile.classpath"/>

        <delete file="../../dist/idp"/>
        <mkdir dir="../../dist/idp"/>
        <mkdir dir="../../dist/idp/META-INF"/>
        <mkdir dir="../../dist/idp/WEB-INF"/>
        <mkdir dir="../../dist/idp/WEB-INF/classes"/>
        <mkdir dir="../../dist/idp/WEB-INF/lib"/>

        <copy todir="../../dist/idp/META-INF">
        <fileset dir="../../idp/src/main/webapp/META-INF"/>
        </copy>
        <copy todir="../../dist/idp/WEB-INF">
        <fileset dir="../../idp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF"/>
        </copy>

        <javac srcdir="../../idp/src/main/java" destdir="../../dist/idp/WEB-INF/classes" classpathref="compile.classpath"/>
        <copy todir="../../dist/idp/WEB-INF/lib" flatten="true">
        <fileset refid="runtime.fileset"/> 
        </copy>
        <delete file="${app.deploy_dir}/config/${app.domainname}/applications/els.ear_dir/${ARTIFACT_ID}-${VERSION}.war"/>
        <zip destfile="${app.deploy_dir}/config/${app.domainname}/applications/els.ear_dir/${ARTIFACT_ID}-${VERSION}.war" basedir="../../dist/idp"/>
        </target>
```